# Read two strings with one scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the scanner which firstly reads the title and then should read two words typed by the user divided with the space and  put them into director name and director surname: but with the code below I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at MainSystem.addBook(MainSystem.java:57)
at MainSystem.main(MainSystem.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Code:

```
private static void addBook() {

    System.out.println("\nEnter title: ");
    title = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("\nEnter director: ");
    String[] parts = scanner.next().split(" ");
    directorName = parts[0];
    directorSurname = parts[1];
```

}

EDIT:
In order to invoke the method add book I also earlier using the scanner - maybe it is the problem:

```
 System.out.println("\nEnter 0 for loading the Library." +
                            "\nEnter 1 for save and quit" +
                            "\nEnter 2 for list all the Books in the Library." +
                            "\nEnter 3 for add Book to the Library.");

int answer = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: next() reads up to the next space, so your array will only contain one element, yet you try to read the second element. try scanner.nextLine() instead

Comment: @Dawid please check my answer below and let me know if you are facing any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take input using nextLine method. Below is the working version I tried in eclipse

Edit: Updated the code as per new edit in the question. Whenever integer is given as input and hit enter, the newline goes as input to the next scanner. So, write a nextLine() after taking the input. Updated code works as per the edited question.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Snippet {
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter 0 for loading the Library."
            + "\nEnter 1 for save and quit"
            + "\nEnter 2 for list all the Books in the Library."
            + "\nEnter 3 for add Book to the Library.");

    int answer = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    if(answer == 3)
        addBook();
}

private static void addBook() {
    System.out.println("Enter title: ");
    String title = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter director: ");
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    String directorName = parts[0];
    String directorSurname = parts[1];
    System.out.println("title : " + title);
    System.out.println("directorname : " + directorName);
    System.out.println("directorsurname : " + directorSurname);
}
}
```

Comment: I edited my question - maybe it is the problem because I tried your solution but it is omitting the title input during runtime

Comment: @Dawid updated my answer, works fine for your requirement. Please let me know if you have any more problems.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `scanner.nextLine()` to consume the whole line, you should be using the proper regex expression to denote at least one whitespace character.

```
String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: I am still getting the error:                  Enter title: 
asd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at MainSystem.addBook(MainSystem.java:56)
 at MainSystem.main(MainSystem.java:35)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Comment: Make sure you use scanner.nextLine() to consume the title as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` will give you only one word, use `scanner.nextLine()` instead.

so you end up with

`String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");`

Also, modify title input as:

`title = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: in that case I am getting the error after typing the title

Comment: in case with: title = scanner.nextLine(); - it totally omits the title input during runtime

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would work - but as you can see I edited the question and the problem was that I used the same scanner before to invoke the addBook method.

```
 int answer = scanner.nextInt();
 scanner.nextLine();


 System.out.println("\nEnter title: ");

    title = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nEnter director: ");
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    directorName = parts[0];
    directorSurname = parts[1];
```